# Tensorboard no runtime metadata

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, tensorboard

I'm trying to profile a Tensorflow graph in Tensorboard, but despite recording runtime metadata, the "Compute time" colour option is greyed out.  A simple example as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.constant(1.0)
y = tf.constant(2.0)
z = x + y

writer = tf.summary.Filewriter('logs', sess.graph)
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_meta = tf.RunMetadata()
res = sess.run(z, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_meta)
writer.add_run_metadata(run_meta, "metadata")
writer.close()
```

I then run Tensorboard from the terminal:

```sh
$ tensorboard --logdir logs
```

I then navigate to http://localhost:6006 in Chrome, and can see the TF graph visualisation, but no performance stats.  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,

Chris

Specs: OSX Mojave, Anaconda Python 3.6.8, Tensorflow 1.14.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered!  The piece I was missing was the dropdown "Tag" menu in the Tensorboard navigation panel on the left hand side of the brower window.  I clicked it, and hey presto, I have "Compute Time" available to me.

Thanks all,

Chris